# counting binary tree leaves at depth

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to create a function that would count leaves of a tree at a specified level from root node.

meaning i have a function leafcount(BTNode node, int level)

A call to this function leafCount(root,2) for a tree structure like below should yield 1 ie it calculates the leaf node B at level 2 from root. It ignores other leaf C as it is not on level 2 but level 1

```
        root
       /    \
      A      C 
     /
    B
```

I tried implementing following using recursion

```
int leafCount(BTNode node, int level){

if(node == null){
 return 0;
}
if(level == 0 && (node.left == null && node.right == null)){
 return 1;
}
else{
 return leafCount(node.left,level--) + leafCount(node.right,level--);
}
```

Though it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have two calls to level--. Better to have a level-- before the recursion call and just send level to recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the post-decrement operator by putting level--. So level-- is happening after the function call instead of before. Also you would be decrementing level twice if you changed to pre-decrement --level. Just put level-- as a line of code one time above your recursive function calls, and then just pass in level to the function calls. Also if level == 0 you can return 0 or 1 without exploring the rest of the tree below the node. This will speed up the search somewhat if your tree is much deeper than the desired level you want to find leaves at.